# Three Js How to copy Object direction that it's facing

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm currently making a 3d space fighter game for my school project, but I encounter a problem when I want to spawn a projectile according to my ship front face or direction it's facing.

I do find a way to spawn projectile according direction we are facing using vector in the following example
http://www.isaacsukin.com/news/2012/06/how-build-first-person-shooter-browser-threejs-and-webglhtml5-canvas

but I still does'nt undestand how this vector work. Can someone explain to me ?

Comment: This is not the place to ask questions about general programming concepts. Search google or youtube for vectors or maybe "game programming vectors"

Comment: I kinda did, and found this but I don't really get how vectors works. Well if it's not okay to ask it's here I  try search for more.

Answer (score -1):

I understand it is more an linear algebra question than programming. First you must fully understand, what `Vector` is, and what isn't.

Often **mistake** is, that a `Vector` is some coordinate in 3D space (x,y,z). This is no true and this thinking will not allow understand, how to correctly work with vectors in space and let's you ask questions like this one.

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors-and-spaces

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors-and-spaces/vectors/v/vector-introduction-linear-algebra

If you need only to copy object rotation, you can use `obj2.rotation.set(obj1.rotation.x,obj1.rotation.y,obj1.rotation.z)`
If you want so put something to the space object facing, you can use object as parent:

```
var my_vect = new THREE.Object3D(); // create vector
obj1.add(my_vect); // add to your object
obj1.rotation.set(1,2,3); // rotate object
my_vect.position.translateX(1); // move vector 1 unit before the object
obj1.localToWorld( my_vect.position); // get global coords from local coords
```

actually my_vect.position.x,my_vect.position.y,my_vect.position.z are the numbers in your scene before the object respecting object orientation.

Comment: (1) use `obj2.rotation.copy( obj1.rotation );` (2) `obj1.add( my_vect );` -- you can't add a `Vector3` as a child of an object.

Comment: (1) yes, i want to show the vectorYXZ usage.
(2) i dont realized, i edited answer